# is eZ components safe to use in development?

Tags: php, zend-framework, workflow, zeta-components

I'm developing a system using Zend Framework 1.xx and I want to add workflow to my system. Because ZF doesn't have any component for workflow I want to use eZ Components workflow component to design my System's workflow engine but it seems that ezc stable release did not changes since 2009.
Now my question is, development of workflow engine based on eZc is safe?
I saw Zeta Components, Is Zeta Components the continue of eZ Components?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

eZ Components are originally developped by eZ Systems and were supposed to be maintained by Apache Foundation under the name "Zeta Components". But due to some time constraints, core developers had to retire it from Apache and put it on [Github](https://github.com/zetacomponents)

eZ Components were developed by [Sebastian Bergmann](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/), [Kore Nordmann](http://kore-nordmann.de/), [Derick Rethans](http://derickrethans.nl/), and [Tobias Schlitt](http://schlitt.info/) who are both four pretty experienced with PHP.

Just check their rank on http://www.ohloh.net...

So here are 5 reasons why you may use it anyway:

- I guess that even if they did not change since 2009, it's safer to use than new libraries coded by any anonymous guy...
- If you have a look to authors' blogs, you'll see that there is still some activity
- It seems that it's still used by eZ Publish and even by the well known PHPUnit (from Bergmann)
- Code is clear, so easier to debug if you experiment some issues.
- The more people use it, the more people may correct it

And here are 2 reasons why not to use it:

- No support
- Very little community

According to your own project constraints, you may chose to use the workflow component or not. But in my own opinion, the best way to make a choice is just to test it.